# Select max of a column based on another column ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the maximum salary for each year in a table with the attributes teamID, salary, yearID. Shouldn't be hard right? Here is my query:

```
SELECT teamID, MAX(tS.teamSalary), yearID
FROM
  (SELECT
      teamID,
      sum(salary) AS teamSalary,
      yearID
    FROM salaries
    GROUP BY teamID, yearID) tS
GROUP BY yearID;
```

The inner query works just fine, but the outer one is just reporting the first teamID for each group. What am I doing wrong?

```
Inner query output:
A  1  2000
B  1  2000 
C  2  2000
A  2  2001
B  3  2001
A  2  2002
B  2  2002

Full query output: 
A  1  2000
A  2  2001
A  2  2002

Desired output: 
C  2  2000
B  3  2001
A  2  2002
```

Comment: Do you need the TeamID in this if you're just doing for each year?

Comment: Yes, this is a subquery for the final bit which will retrieve the team name from another table.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you *actually* want out of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get maxSalary by year, then you get the extra information:

```
SELECT teamID, salary, yearID
  FROM salaries 
  JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(salary) AS maxSalary,
            yearID
       FROM salaries
   GROUP BY yearID) tS
    ON ts.yearID = salaries.yearID
   AND ts.maxSalary = salaries.salary
```

EDIT: Not sure if you want the max salary of some year, then to which team it belongs, or if you want the max salary by team and year. The second option is here:

```
  SELECT MAX(salary) AS maxSalary, yearID, teamID
    FROM salaries
GROUP BY yearID, teamID
```

Comment: I switched over to finding max first then using a join and that seems to have worked. Thank you for your help!